# Why is my mvc3 viewmodel not updating correctly?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am writing an image upload form using ASP.NET MVC 3.

In the view, please notice that I am displaying `@Model.ImagePath` as text and as a `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ImagePath)`.

#### View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype="multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.BannerSlideId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Key)
    <p>
    Image Path:@(Model.ImagePath)<br />
    Image Path in TextBoxFor: @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ImagePath)
    </p>
    <p>
        <label class="styled">Upload Slide Image</label>
        <input type="file" name="image" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <button type="submit">Save</button> @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </p>
}
```

I then select an image using the file input, and I submit the form to the Controller.

#### Controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(BannerSlide model, HttpPostedFileBase image)
{
    if (image != null)
        model.ImagePath = image.FileName;
    return View("Edit", model);
}
```

When I debug with a breakpoint, the `image.FileName` string **is** assigned to `model.ImagePath`. However, when I get back to the **View** I get Two different values from `ImagePath`.

#### Results

```
Image Path:@(Model.ImagePath)<br />
```

Correctly returns the image filename that was assigned. But,

```
Image Path in TextBoxFor: @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ImagePath)
```

**Incorrectly** returns blank!

Any ideas for why this is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should remove the ImagePath property from ModelState if you intend to modify it in your POST controller action or HTML helpers such as TextBoxFor will first look for a value inside ModelState when binding and then in the model:

```
if (image != null)
{
    ModelState.Remove("ImagePath");
    model.ImagePath = image.FileName;
}
```

Comment: @quakkels, because I don't want to be a moderator.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for all your help here in SO. You've helped me many times before, both through my questions and through others' questions.

Answer (score 2):

The `TextBoxFor` HtmlHelper method, and all input helper methods for that matter, set the value of the input control to the value held in `ModelState` rather than immediately binding to the property of the ViewModel.  Since the ImagePath present in the POST to your Create method, it is displayed as a blank value on the subsequent Response.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use following attribute on such actions

```
public class ModelStateFixAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public ModelStateFixAttribute()
    {

    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        ModelStateDictionary modelState = filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState;

        String[] arrKeys = new string[modelState.Keys.Count];
        modelState.Keys.CopyTo(arrKeys, 0);
        foreach (string key in arrKeys)
        {
            if (modelState.IsValidField(key))
                modelState.Remove(key);
        }
    }
}
```